# How do I route this in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

*Im new to MVC.*

I have a controller for some charts (ChartsController), where I have an action result

```
public ActionResult TheChart { ...etc
```

I then have a View which displays the chart (its a Highcharts chart using javascript). This calls its data via this

```
public JsonResult GetData(string id) { ..etc
```

All works well.

I want to now add a parameter so that I can slightly change my javascript in the view for certain conditions. (Display for printing)
I was thinking something like

```
public ActionResult TheChart(string mediaType)
{ 
     if (mediaType="print"){
            ViewData["pdf"] = true;
     }
}
```

Then I can grab this in the view.

The problem is that now my JsonResult doesnt work ( I think due to the routing ). 
Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Please tell us more accurately which requests are processed and which are not. What do you mean by "my JsonResult doesn't work"? Your code isn't hit? Your client doesn't receive the result? Do you mean that http://mysite/Controller/TheChart?mediaType=pdf is received and proceesed correctly but afterwards http://mysite/Controller/GetData/id isn't hit by your server code? Did you use a sniffer such as WireShark to see what happens on the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you have (string mediaType)

what you need is a new route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("all-user", "Controller/TheChart/{mediaType}",
                        new { controller = "Controller", action = "TheChart"});
```

this goes inside your Global.asax file incase you havent used these yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a typo here or did you really write `if (mediaType="print"){`? There is an equal sign missing.